# missing operator= in class

Tags: c++, std

I have the following class, here is it full prototype:

```
class FlowEdge{
private:
    const uint32_t from_;
    const uint32_t to_;
    const double capacity_;
    double flow_;
public:
    FlowEdge();
    FlowEdge(uint32_t from, uint32_t to, double capacity);
    uint32_t from() const;
    uint32_t to() const;
    uint32_t other(uint32_t vertex) const throw(std::invalid_argument);
    double getCapacity() const;
    double getFlow() const;
    double residualCapacityTo(uint32_t vertex) const throw(std::invalid_argument);
    void addResidualFlowTo(uint32_t vertex, double delta) throw(std::invalid_argument);
};
```

I use this class as std::deque element type: `std::deque<FlowEdge>` in another class. When I compile my project I receive an error said that my `FlowEdge` class have no available `operator=` method. This method is created by compiler by default, isn't it? What could be a problem? I haven't `operator=` nor in public, nor in protected section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler generates an `operator=` for you *if it is able to do so.* It's not able in your case, because you have a `const` member in the class. Such a member cannot be assigned to, so the default copy assignment operator wouldn't be well-defined. If you want to assign objects of this class, you have to provide a custom one, implementing it to preserve the semantics you want of the `const` member.

Of course, the easier alternative would be to make `capacity_` a non-const `double`. Generally, `const` data members are only useful in very specific situations, and they're usually more trouble than they're worth.

Comment: For more information on default copy assignment operators, see [the C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator).